# What is the difference between monitoring and profiling?

Tags: profiling, monitoring, distributed-computing

What is the difference between monitoring and profiling? Why do some people say that tools for application monitoring should not be used for profiling?

Comment: Monitoring = keeping an eye on how an application is running (memory usage, CPU, disk use etc). Profiling = measuring performance (speed) by running the code and timing how long each step takes.

Answer (score 2):

Profiling comes before deployment and monitoring comes after.
So it is probably not a good idea to use the same tool for both